# React Native, MobX and lifecycle

Tags: javascript, react-native, lifecycle, mobx

I'm using MobX in React Native and so far I really lite it.
Is there some lifecycle or method to call a function when the state in Mobx Store is changed?

Comment: You can use mobx [reaction](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/reaction.html) method

Answer (score 1):

`componentWillReceiveProps` can be used in the component level. For instance, observer container will notify the actual component through props (imaginary use case in TypeScript):

```
@inject('notificationStore')
@observer
class SomeContainer extends Component<Props> {
  ...

  public render(): JSX.Element {
    <Notification
      message={this.props.notificationStore.message}
      ...
    />
  }
}
```

And in Notification:

```
class Notification extends PureComponent<Props> {
  ...
  public componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps: any): void {
    Alert.alert('message', nextProps.message);
  }
}
```

Now, when you mutate `notificationStore.message` eg. *'Hello world'*, it will displayed by Notification component.

If you want more direct approach, then you just inject the component with store and observe the changes. Basically your TypeScript interface should look like this:

```
interface Props {
  notificationStore?: any;
  ...
}
```

As you can see, store is always considered as a prop and this means the mutation will trigger `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle event.

Hope I explained this clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can put an [**autorun**](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/autorun.html) in `componentDidMount` and dispose it in `componentWillUnmount`:

**Example ([JSBin](http://jsbin.com/koxuguxano/1/edit?js,console,output))**

```
const store = observable({
  data: "data"
});

setTimeout(() => {
  store.data += " updated!";
}, 2000);

@observer
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.disposer = autorun(() => {
      console.log(`Data changed: ${this.props.store.data}`);
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.disposer();
  }

  render() {
    return <h1>{this.props.store.data}</h1>;
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <App store={store} />,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```